# When do I need to use the output (h_0) of GRU network as input for next step?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to train an A3C agent with nn model that contains **GRU layer/s.** And I'm not sure I'm using the second output (h_n) in my training and testing correctly!

Keeping this as simple as possible, let's take the below model as example:

```
model = nn.GRU(input_size=1024, hidden_size=128, num_layers=1)
observation = torch.randn(1,1,1024)
```

**While Training:**
At the beginning of each episode, I'm feeding observation `obs0` and `None` to get the first `output` and `h_n`.
Then I calculate `action` from `output` and step the environment to get the next observation `obs1`, which I'm using alongside `h1` as inputs for next step

1-    `output, h_n = model(obs0)`
2-    `output, h_n = model(obs1, h_n)`

And so on until the episode ends or I have enough samples for my batch.

**My questions here:**
*is that correct?* *if Yes, do I need to detach h_n at each step or keep the gradient and detach only at the 1-end of the episode OR 2- end of batch?*

**Testing:**
Testing is similar to training where initial h_n is None, then updating it from the model output and use it as input for the next step ---> until episode ends (no need to detach since i'm decorating with @torch.no_grad())

Is that the correct implementation?

Comment: I started writing an answer then realized too much information is missing from the question. You have to at least provide a relevant paper, or explain why a GRU makes sense here, and distinguish the concept of time (in GRU) from the concept of episodes (in RL) and how they interact in your case.

Comment: Please also read about [TBPTT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255203/can-someone-please-explain-the-truncated-back-propagation-through-time-algorithm)

Comment: It seems from your question that you are trying to refer to episodes as you would to time, which makes no sense. Where does the Bellman equation come in to the GRU? Maybe these things are solved, but you have to cite them to get a meaningful answer